# How to create a UIImage from whatever is in the background

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ios7

I am applying blur to various sections of my app using the UIImage+ImageEffects.h sample code that was provided in one of the apps from the WWDC in 2013.  It works well and I'm able to recreate the iOS7 effects for any UIImage.

However, I would like to recreate the effect of the UINavigationBar blurred transparency but using any view that I choose. Similar to the screenshot shown below.

For instance, say that I have a UITableView that takes up half of the screen.  I also have a UIImageView background as a separate view behind it that occupies the entire screen.  I would only like to blur the UIImageView background for just that section of the screen that's under the tableview.

Here's my question.  How do I create create a UIImage by taking a "screenshot" of whatever is behind a UIView that is displayed?  Is this even possible?

[image: screenshot]

Here is my screen hierarchy.  Nothing complex.  I would like the "Blurred Image View" to contain a blurred image of the section of the "Image View" that is sitting as the main UIImageView in the hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploing only on iOS7 you can use the new api, that are a lot faster than `-renderInContext` and use the ImageEffects category on that image taken from the view. Add this a a category on `UIView`

```
@interface UIView (RenderView)

- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingView;
- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingViewOpaque:(BOOL) yesOrNO;


@end

@implementation UIView (RenderView)

- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingViewOpaque:(BOOL) yesOrNO {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, yesOrNO, 0);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
        [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    }
    else {
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingView{
    return [self imageByRenderingViewOpaque:NO];
}
```

This snippet is a UIView category  ok also for system lower than iOS7. It takes an image on a view and its subviews.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  I'm not sure that drawViewHierarchyInRect is what I'm looking for. The screenshot posted illustrates.  I'm not sure how it's possible that the UINavigationBar in the screenshot has the UIWebView as a subview.  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: -drawViewHierarchyInRect should be the same as -renderInContex but faster, I've never tried with UIWebview, I'm aware that you cannot take screenshot if the baking layer is a particular layer (such as OpenGl Layer, camera preview layer and it doesn't work fine with tiled layer), I don't really know with web views. But pay attention that you are drawing a hierarchy so the message should be sent into the "containing" view, and that the screen should be taken after the web page has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I used the UIWebview as an corresponding example to the screenshot.  My implementation is nothing like that and involves static UIImageViews.  Plain vanilla stuff.  I've called this method from every view in the hierarchy from the main containing view down and get a blank image returned every time, not nil, blank... Again, I'm not sure what's happening here.

Comment: To help explain I've posted the outline of my view Hierarchy.

Comment: well don't know..but from your xib it seems that all your hierarchy is hosted by a subclass of UIView, are you sure that you are taking the screen shot at the right time? . To be sure that is working just modify the method commenting out the if except for renderInContext.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below piece of code for iOS < 7

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```